# Is it possible to impliment web moduls such as News, Image Gallery and etc In One web app with ASP.NET membership Profile?

Tags: asp.net

If it's okay, please present me with your solution.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are actually asking. Please try to rephrase the question to describe the problem you are having and express what kind of solutions you are interested in.

Comment: question is very clear for every one know membership in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Membership was designed solely for security; it wasn't meant as a module built-in feature.  Look for a modular framework that may be open source, or depending on your needs, using web parts framework may be all that you need?

HTH.